# 'Contact us' translation in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, translation

I need to translate the text marked with red. It's not a new string, I haven't added it, it's included in the stock version of Prestashop.

[image]

It seems to be in the 'Front office' section of the localization settings.
I have done the translation, but the text won't change to the translated version.

Just to test it, I have changed the English version to something else (attached as well), but it won't update either.
[image]

Disabled and cleared Prestashop cache multiple times. Cleared browser cache as well.

Prestashop version 1.7.8.8, default theme.

Comment: When you say you cleared the cache, do you mean in prestashop or from your browser?

Comment: I meant the Prestashop cache. Just edited original question for clarity.

Comment: Try a forced compilation and see if the `asd` text appears.

Answer (score 0):

Shop parameters -> Traffic & SEO -> SEO & URLS -> 'contact' page.

Because of course, why would it be under 'Translations'?

V1.7.8.8